# Find all overlapping records in multiple lists

Tags: python

How to find overlapping records in multiple lists (about 100)?

```
dct = {'One':   [1,2,3],
       'Two':   [3],
       'Three': [0,1,5],
       'Four':  [2,5,10,11]}
```

I have difficulty on the planning stage, if I to draw block diagram with sequence what steps it should include?

My solution is comparing every list against each all other lists minus the one, but this will use so many loops, guess there should be better approach. I know about `set.intersection()`, but how can I apply it here with more than two lists?

Output needs to count numbers that repeat in every list i.e.

```
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Please post the actual code of your proposed solution, and not just a rough description.  And a better description of the problem (examples would be great).

Comment: I have no code working code i said i dont understand what needs to be done in first place, i can count with my finger, but how do it with code no idea how

Comment: I think he means, for the example solution, what are you expecting? By overlapping records, do you mean records that overlap in all of the lists or just between two or more lists? What do you expect the output format to be?

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse the dictionary:

```
dct = {'One':   [1,2,3],
       'Two':   [3],
       'Three': [0,1,5],
       'Four':  [2,5,10,11]}

rev_dct = {}

for k in dct:
    for val in dct[k]:
        if val in rev_dct:
            rev_dct[val].append(k)
        else:
            rev_dct[val] = [k]
```

`rev_dct` Output:

```
{1: ['One', 'Three'],
 2: ['One', 'Four'],
 3: ['One', 'Two'],
 0: ['Three'],
 5: ['Three', 'Four'],
 10: ['Four'],
 11: ['Four']}
```

Comment: Suggest using `collections.defaultdict`.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the question correctly, you can create a map of the values while going over lists just once and keep it like `1` is in `["one", "three"...` ]

```
   includes = {
       {1: ['One', 'Three'],
    ...

   }
```

if any of the list values of the new dict is the length of the initial dict's keys, that one is in all of the initial lists